# What do you call the flat part of the circular saw?

Tags: word-request

[image: Hand-held circular saw]

What do you call the flat part of the circular saw? Is it called a rest?

I am talking about the flat rectangular part attached to it with a hole in the middle to let the blade go through the rectangle. I am not sure what it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing an image search for "circular saw parts", shows images like the following, so the part appears to be called a **base plate**.
[image]

Other images also refer to it as just a "base", or just a "plate".